# How can I update data for a selected row?

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli, sql-update

I'm learning PHP, html, and sql.  I am trying to create a form that allows users to update data on existing customers.  I was wondering what went wrong with my code because every time I tried to make changes on an existing customer, the changes are reflected on the first customer of the data set.  For example, when I changed the data for customer ID #14, the changes are shown in customer ID #1.  Customer ID #14 still holds the old data.  Here is my code. Can someone give me some tips on how to fix it?  I spent hours on this, but I don't know what I'm missing.  Thanks a lot!

This is part of the code in the main.php file.

```
<div>
            <form method="post" action="updatecustomer.php">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Update Existing Customer</legend>
                    <li>First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"> Last Name: <input type="text" name="lName"</li>
                    <li>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email"></li>
                    <li>Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone_number"></li>
                    <li>Street Number: <input type="text" name="address_no"> Street Line 1: <input type="text" name="address_street1"></li>
                    <li>Street Line 2 (Apt or Unit Number): <input type="text" name="address_street2"></li>
                    <li>City: <input type="text" name="address_city"> State: <input type="text" name="address_state"> Zip: <input type="text" name="address_zip"> </li>
                    <li>Customer ID:
                        <select name="customer_id">
        <?php
        if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT customer_id, customer_id FROM customer"))){
            echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
        }

        if(!$stmt->execute()){
            echo "Execute failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }
        if(!$stmt->bind_result($customer_id, $customer_id)){
            echo "Bind failed: "  . $mysqli->connect_errno . " " . $mysqli->connect_error;
        }

        while($stmt->fetch()){
            echo '<option value=" '. $customer_id . ' "> ' . $customer_id . '</option>\n';
        }

        $stmt->close();
        ?>
                        </select>
                    </li>
                </fieldset>
                <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Customer">
        </div>
```

Here is the updatecustomer.php code:

```
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE customer SET fName=?, lName=?, email=?, phone_number=?, address_no=?, address_street1=?, 
    address_street2=?, address_city=?, address_state=?, address_zip=? WHERE customer_id =?"))){
    echo "Prepare failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}

if(!($stmt->bind_param("sssiissssii",$_POST['fName'],$_POST['lName'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['phone_number'], $_POST['address_no'],
    $_POST['address_street1'],$_POST['address_street2'],$_POST['address_city'],$_POST['address_state'], $_POST['address_zip'], $_POST['customer_id']))){
    echo "Bind failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
}
if(!$stmt->execute()){
    echo "Execute failed: "  . $stmt->errno . " " . $stmt->error;
} else {
    echo "Updated " . $stmt->affected_rows . " rows to customer.";
}
```

Comment: why exactly are you fetching customer_id twice in the same query? `select customer_id from ...` is more than enough.

Comment: Your customer_id variable should contain the id of the customer you want to modify (14 in your example), but it seems that it contains another one (1 in your case). Be sure to pass the correct customer_id to your query.

Comment: @eternay: I'm very new to php and mysqli. Do u mind to give me more details on how I can pass the correct customer_id to my query? Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you're doing it correctly: you pass it through the form submit, with the `select` html element. Then you get it back in your `updatecustomer.php` thanks to the `bind_param()` method. Your update query seems correct, I can't see the problem, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but try to remove spaces here first `value=" '. $customer_id . ' "` because this will send you a string type value like `string(4) " 14 "`. I'd go for `intval($_POST['customer_id'])` next.